# How To Change OS Windows from Web App?

Tags: java

I am writing a web app with java. I am curious to know if there is a way that I can switch between the browser window (running the web app) and a local Java client application window (standard Java window). The Java Window is Oracle Forms.

For example, when i'm running the web app in my internet browser and I click a button. I want the button to execute process to switch from the internet browser window to the local java/forms window. Thus I would need something to execute on the OS level to switch my window.

How could I do this? I'm interested in any idea that would make that usecase work. For example, I probably need to introduce and integrate new technologies with my app? Probably a Java Applet?

Thank you,

Gavin

Comment: I'd avoid applets if you can, they'd have to be signed and that's generally a bother. Use custom URLs that will "launch" your client application. (The same way Apple redirects you to the iTunes Music Store, or how bittorrent clients can open magnet links.) You can embed whatever data (i.e. a command) you want into the URL. You'll have to consult the documentation for whatever you're developing your client application in to see how to handle custom URLs and how to register your app as the handler in the OS though.

Comment: I was reading about Java FX 2.0.
I belive this framework can it for you. This link is a good first step: http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/48067

Comment: cool thanks! I'm a bit a newb here. What do you mean by registering my app as a handler in the OS? Any examples?

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I shall check this out and let you know.

Comment: Not really. Web apps aren't really meant to be able to arbitrarily interact with the host OS, which is why doing this is a little complicated. Basically, your app can ask the OS to open a URL for you. Opening a `http://` URL would result in a new browser window opening and loading that URL. So analogously, opening a URL that's handled by your client app will let you pass data to it. MSDN seems to have a fairly complete example of how to do this on Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx. Other OSes probably handle this differently.

Comment: JavaFX will still require being deployed as a signed applet to get out of the sandbox.

Comment: @Will, I respect what you do as a moderator, but closing the question most unnecessary. The guys whom answered my question understood the question well and provided good info. Now that i have time to look into this, i can't use their links and research because you closed the question. Re-open it please.